# Finding general solution of first order

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Given $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=xe^{-2y}$, find a general solution that satisfies $y(0)=2$. My steps are:
$$
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{e^{-2y}}=\int x \mathrm{d}x \implies \ln e^{2y}=x^2 + C \implies y= \frac{\ln(x^2 + C)}{2}.
$$
Then $y(0)=2$ gives
$$
4 = \ln(0 + C) \implies e^4 = C,
$$
so that
$$
y=\frac{\ln{(x^2+e^4)}}{2}.
$$

Is this right?

Comment: Your integrating step needs fixing.

Comment: A few comments: you start off well (the second line is OK) but do not get the right result. A useful though simple tip for the future, if you want to know if you are right just check if your solution indeed verifies the initial equation. Last, there are a few corrections you can make as regards MathJax (use " \ln " instead of plain " ln "). You alse forgot an $x$ in your third line.

Comment: Hmmm... after looking over the rest of your problem, it could be just that you made some type-os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's correct

$$\int\frac{dy}{e^{-2y}}=\int x dx \implies \int{e^{2y}}dy=\int x dx$$
$$\frac {e^{2y}}2=\frac {x^2}2+K \implies e^{2y}=x^2+C$$
$$ y(0)=2 \implies C=e^4$$
$$y(x)=\frac {\ln |x^2+e^4|}2$$

Comment: isnt your answer the same with mine??

Comment: Yes @vik  thats right sorry I corrected my answer I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 2):

$\int \frac{1}{e^{-2y}} dy =\int x dx$

$\int e^{2y} dy=\int x dx$

$\frac{1}{2} e^{2y}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$

Comment: thankyou for the answer :D